# Show hide icon next to input form depending on validation

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I just been asked to design a small login form with 3 labels and input forms as well as a login button. The layout is pretty ready and I took the liberty of placing the warning icons next to each input forms.

Because my knowledge of jquery is very limited and that's precisely what format they asked me, I do not know how to write a validation for each form (for example nulls and minimum characters = 4) resulting in the showing and hiding of the warning icon next to it!

Please help me!

Thankyou

Kind Regards

Tiago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)?

The [demo page](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) should get you started.